# Filter a collection

Tags: c++, collections, stl, comparative-review

In my project, there are some methods which filter some items from a collection. I was told to use the C++ STL whenever I can. But when I use `std::copy_if`, I feel the code using a simple `if`-condition looks cleaner.

Which implementation do you like more?  Which one is more readable?

`std::copy_if` version

```
std::vector<Cat> red_cat_list(const std::vector<Cat>& cat_list)
{
    std::vector<Cat> result_list; // fixed the typo
    std::copy_if(
        cat_list.begin(), 
        cat_list.end(), 
        std::back_insert(result_list),
        [](const Cat& cat){ return cat.color() == Color::RED;});
    return result_list;
}
```

`if`-condition version

```
std::vector<Cat> red_cat_list(const std::vector<Cat>& cat_list)
{
    std::vector<Cat> result_list; // fixed the typo
    for(const auto& cat : cat_list)
        if(cat.color() == Color::RED)
            result_list.push_back(cat);
    return result_list;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version with the range-for is marginally shorter, while `copy_if` more clearly specifies the intended result of the block of code. For readability, I'd call it pretty close to a draw.

You might also want to consider a few alternatives. One obvious one would be a Boost `filter_iterator`. It's probably at least sort of overkill for an operation as simple as you're working with here, but especially when/if you might want to do a little more than just copy the filtered results, such as wanting something like a `transform_if` (which the standard library doesn't supply), a `filter_iterator` might be worth considering.

Comment: Thanks for pointer the typo(I've corrected it). And I will check the BOOST::filter_iterator, it looks what I need. Thank you!